# Tag MP4 Video Files

Tags: ubuntu, mp4

I'm looking for a command-line tool to automatically fetch and tag my MP4 files using data from thetvdb.com.

A Google search didn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that fit my requirements. So I wrote my own tool [AtomicTV](https://rubygems.org/gems/AtomicTV) to do the job. It's a wrapper around AtomicParsley and fetches info from TheTVDB.com.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across anything for Ubuntu yet unfortunately.  The closest I have found is [TVRename](http://www.tvrename.com/) which is for windows.  I haven't managed to get it working in Wine yet either, so I am resorting to running it on a Windows system over the network (but a VM would do just as well).

The source code is available, and I'm sure they'd welcome help in porting it to Linux...

Comment: So thats not quite what I'm looking for. I want a program that can add MP4 tags to a file based on that data.

I'm currently using [tvnamer](https://github.com/dbr/tvnamer) on Ubuntu which does the same job as TVRename.

Comment: Oooh, not come across that one - fantastic stuff - downloading now. No idea with mp4 tags (are they the video equivalent to id3?)